# PHP Object Config XML

Tags: php, object

I'm using a single XML file to store configuration settings for multiple objects. For example:

```
<config>
    <database>
        <user>myuser</user>
    </database>
    <application>
        <component1>mycomponent</component1>
    </application>
    <infrastructure>
        <hostname1>server1</hostname1>
    </infrastructure>
</config>
```

I want each of my objects to access different aspects of the xml; for instance the "database" class would access the database element.

**What method could be used to quickly access this configuration across my objects without reproducing code?**

Comment: What is your measure by which one way might be better than another?

Comment: Re-worded with some measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `Config` object which reads the configuration from the XML file, then use a `Configurable` trait on the classes you want to be "automatically" configurable from the XML (see example below).

config.xml:

```
<config>
    <database>
        <user>myuser</user>
    </database>
    <application>
        <component1>mycomponent</component1>
    </application>
    <infrastructure>
        <hostname1>server1</hostname1>
    </infrastructure>
</config>
```

PHP code:

```
class Config
{
    /**
     * Full XML configuration
     *
     * @var SimpleXMLElement
     */
    private static $xml;

    /**
     * Parse XML configuration file into XML object (once)
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!self::$xml) {
            $xmlSource = file_get_contents('config.xml');
            self::$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlSource);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the first node matching the specified xpath
     *
     * @param $xpath
     *
     * @return SimpleXMLElement
     */
    public function getFirstByXpath($xpath)
    {
        // Return the first matching configuration
        return self::$xml->xpath($xpath)[0];
    }
}

trait Configurable
{
    /**
     * Class configuration XML element
     *
     * @var SimpleXMLElement
     */
    private $configuration;

    /**
     * Get the class configuration XML element
     *
     * @return SimpleXMLElement
     */
    function getConfiguration()
    {
        if (!$this->configuration) {
            $tag = strtolower(get_class($this));
            $xpath = '/config/' . $tag;

            $this->configuration = (new Config())->getFirstByXpath($xpath);
        }

        return $this->configuration;
    }
}

class application
{
    use configurable;
}

class database
{
    use configurable;
}

$app = new application();
echo "App component 1: ", $app->getConfiguration()->component1, PHP_EOL;

$db = new database();
echo "DB user: ", $db->getConfiguration()->user, PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
App component 1: mycomponent
DB user: myuser
```

Comment: How could the trait be handled if the config.xml was variable - set by a class?

Comment: There may be multiple options depending on how to you want to use it - do you have a use case?